# How to make background-image to follow the content and re-scaling together

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background, responsive

I have an issue with finding the solution which will help me to make my square(1692x1773 px) background-image to follow the content in such a way that the content, e.g. header will stay in one of the cells of the background-image either by changing the width or height of the browser window. Basically I want the background-image to be cut automatically depending on the window size, so I don't need to change the image when I will add media queries for smaller screens.

[Please see the attached link to the video for details](https://youtu.be/NQHh6Dsuo9Q)

Comment: You can use `background-size: cover`.

Comment: `background-size: cover` is being used 

`body {
  background: url("../img/index.png");
  background-position: center 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution which fit my purpose just partially. If you see the better way your input will be very appreciated. Unfortunately, I couldn't make a fully responsive page, I had to make adjustments for particular resolutions by using media queries and, of course, this is not what I want to achieve.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/media.css">
    <!-- <script src="script/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> -->
    <title>Веллеречие - В этом весь Веллер</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body-container">
      <h1  class="header">Веллеречие</h1>
      <img class="weller-img" src="img/weller-index.png" alt="Фото Веллера">
      <a class="nav-container nav-item-1" href="#">Литература
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu__list">
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
```

CSS

```
 html, body, h1, *,
*:before,*:after {
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 65px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu__list {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background: url("../img/index.png");
  background-position: center 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu-background {
  background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%,0.7);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

/* Main navigation container */
.body-container {
  /* background-color: hsl(0,0%,100%, 0.6); */
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3.41vh;
  height: 90.3vh;
  width: 847px;
}

/* .nav-container {
  background-color: rgb(60, 43, 126, 0.7);
} */

/* Заголовок сайта Веллеречине */
.header {
  display: block;
  /* background-color: rgb(227, 25, 189, 0.7); */
  position: absolute;
  left: 31.4%;
  top: 47.5%;

  height: 11.4%;
  width: 66.37%;

  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: center;

  color: #0000fd;
  font-size: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Screen examples

1. Widescreen
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7rWS.png)

2.iPhone X
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8vxg.png)